# How can I write a commands in GitBash while npm live-server is working?

Tags: command, git-bash, npm-live-server

I just started working with Git Bash, so I'm trying to do some commands while npm live-server is working, but Git Bash doesn't react at all.
I figured out that I can stop the process with "Ctrl+C" command, but is there a opportunity to do commands without stopping the live-server?
Thanks for your answers!)

Comment: Open another terminal window?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Clive! I understand the method) Now I can write commands while server is working!

Comment: This is not an answer.